# Issues when using ngGrid and OAuth refresh tokens

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have encountered a very annoying issue when using ng-grid 2.0.7 and OAuth2 refresh tokens in my Angular SPA appliction.

My application uses OAuth2 to generate authentication tokens upon login and each time the token expires an HTTP 401 error is generated. Then, I have
an AngularJS response interceptor that intercepts HTTP 401 errors and requests a new refresh token before retrying the previous HTTP request again.  Now, all of this works beautifully throughout my application **EXCEPT** when using ng-grid.

This is a portion of the code in my AngularJS controller that is causing me no end of problems:

```
appModule.controller('orderBookController',
    ['$scope', '$timeout', 'orderList',
        function ($scope, $timeout, orderList) {

            $scope.orders = [];
            $scope.orderList = orderList;

            // get data asynchronously and return the list of orders via a promise. 
            self.getDataAsync = function () {
                $scope.orderList.getOrders()
                .then(function (data) {
                    // THIS BIT IS WHAT I AM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH.
                    // $scope.orders gets populated with new data, but
                    // doesn't appear in the grid at all.
                    $timeout(function () {
                        console.log($scope.$$phase);
                        console.log(data.orders);
                        $scope.orders = data.orders;
                    }, 3000);
                })
            };

            // load initial data.
            self.getDataAsync();

            // set up ng-grid
            $scope.orderData = {
                columnDefs: [
                    { field: 'orderRef', displayName: 'Order Ref', width: 75 },
                    { field: 'customerName', displayName: 'Customer Name' },
                ],
                multiSelect: false,
                headerRowHeight: 48,
                rowHeight: 30,
                showFooter: true,
                data: 'orders'
            };

        }
    ]);
```

The problem is when the application encounters a 401 error and a new refresh token has been received the ng-grid remains blank even though the developer
console log clearly shows the data sent by the REST back end. If I go to another page immediately and then come back the grid refreshes fine and shows the data, but if I wait until
the token expires it doesn't show the data and the grid remains blank.

This is making me wonder whether there is an issue with ng-grid not refreshing when it receives the data during the $digest cycle.  I can confirm that `$scope.$$phase` displays
`$digest` in the developer console when `$timeout` is executing.

Has anyone come across this before and how do I solve it?

At worst I will have to ditch ng-grid and either go with [SmartTable](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) or roll my own custom grid.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve my own issue after I realised that the `getOrders()` method was falling into the `error` callback and was therefore rejecting the response.  After changing the `error` callback so that it does a `deferred.resolved(self)` appropriately sorted out the issue.